# Using PHP Resize & Crop Image Using Specific Format

Tags: php, image

There are plenty of PHP resizing image scripts out there such as [this one](http://www.nimrodstech.com/php-image-resize/), however I'm pretty new to PHP and need help with a specific format I've already made using JQuery/HTML5;

```
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        width = $('#blah').width(); // Current image width
        height = $('#blah').height(); // Current image height
        if ( width > 119 && height > 119 ){
            if (width > height) {
                ratio = width / height; // get ratio for scaling image
                newWidth = 120 * ratio;
                margin = '-' + (newWidth - 120) /2 + 'px';
                $('img#blah').css("width", newWidth + 'px'); // Set new width
                $('img#blah').css("height", '120px'); // Scale height based on ratio
                $('#blah').css("margin-left", margin);
            }
            if (height > width) {
                ratio = height / width; // get ratio for scaling image
                newHeight = 120 * ratio;
                margin = '-' + (newHeight - 120) /2 + 'px';
                $('img#blah').css("height", newHeight + 'px'); // Set new width
                $('img#blah').css("width", '120px'); // Scale height based on ratio
                $('#blah').css("margin-top", margin);
            }
```

I've made a [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qohtqje5/) to show the working outcome of what my full script does. I'm now attempting to upload a scaled cropped version to a specific dir on my server.

Comment: This won't work. You have to do this serverside. jQuery is just asking to browser to resize the image on the fly, but it does not change its initial resolution.

Comment: I understand that. I am wanting to know how I can replicate what my JQuery/HTML5 is doing in PHP then upload to my server.

Comment: If you do this with PHP, it will already be on the server. No need to upload anything. You will have to give it a try before asking

Comment: Well my [linked image resize](http://www.nimrodstech.com/php-image-resize/) does pretty much everything for me to give a days work to get perfect however it is mainly the centering crop I do not have any idea how to achieve.